# Braintree multiple authorizations

Tags: braintree

We have integrated Braintree for credit card payments. Business model is such, we ask for a downpayment of 30% to book our service and remaining 70% after the job is done. So initially we take the 30% payment, but what would be the best way to take the remaining 70% later. One way is to authorise 70% while taking 30% and keep on re-authorising till the job is done. But we are ok with not holding the amount for the entire time before charging. Can we authorise & take the 70% directly after the job is done?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

If you [vault](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/overview) the customer's [payment method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create/ruby), you can create another transaction without needing to reauthorize.

Answer (score 0):

If your customer agrees to have their card vaulted then you can charge the remainder without authorisation.